# Bison - nonterminals useless in grammar

Tags: bison

0

I am doing my homework assignment and I am having some errors in the bison file. I got error like 'blabla' has no declared type. My code and errors are below. I am trying do a type checker, I have a header, flex and a bison file. Flex returning the tokens that I need. I wrote a function to make an attribute, then I check if the two attribute types are the same or not. If not same, I will give an error output, but when I compile it I got these errors. I did not figure it out. What did I do wrong?

In bison file:

```
    %{
 void yyerror(char *s);
 int yylex();
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 int symbols[52];
 int symbolVal(char symbol);
 void updateSymbolVal(char symbol, int val);
%}

%union {int num,char id}

%token DOGRULUK
%token PARANTEZ_AC
%token PARANTEZ_KAPA
%token ISE
%token NOKTA
%token EGER
%token YADA
%token YOKSA
%token YORUM
%token YORUM_AC
%token YORUM_KAPA
%token ESITTIR
%token VEYA
%token DEGIL
%token DEMEK
%token ANCAKVEANCAK
%token VE
%token KUCUKESIT
%token KUCUKTUR
%token BUYUKESIT
%token BUYUKTUR

%token EKRANAYAZ
%token TARA
%token DONGU
%token ARTI
%token EKSI
%token BOLU
%token CARPI
%token KALAN
%token CALISTIR
%token BOLUM
%token SAYI
%token YAZIDIZISI
%token conditional_expression
%token identifier
%token left_hand_side


%right ESITTIR BUYUKTUR KUCUKTUR BUYUKESIT KUCUKESIT
%nonassoc ANCAKVEANCAK VE VEYA DEGIL DEMEK

%type <id> identifier
%type <num>  assignment_expression relational_expression assignment conditional_expression left_hand_side expression

%%

type : YAZIDIZISI |
        SAYI



expression: assignment_expression ';' {$$ = $1;}
          | relational_expression ';' {$$ = $1;};

relational_expression: expression  ESITTIR expression  ';'      { $$ = $1 == $3;}
                      |expression  KUCUKTUR expression  ';'     { $$ = $1 < $3;}
                      |expression  KUCUKESIT expression  ';'    { $$ = $1 <= $3;}
                      |expression  BUYUKTUR expression  ';'     { $$ = $1 > $3;}
                      |expression  BUYUKESIT expression ';'     { $$ = $1 => $3;}
                      |expression  ANCAKVEANCAK expression ';'  { $$ = $1 <=> $3;}
                      |expression  DEMEK expression     ';'     { $$ = $1 => $3;}
                      |expression  VE expression    ';'         { $$ = $1 && $3;}
                      |expression  VEYA expression   ';'        { $$ = $1 || $3;}
                      |expression  DEGIL expression  ';'        { $$ = $1 != $3;};

assignment_expression: conditional_expression ';' {$$ = $1;}
                      |assignment           ';'   {$$ = $1;};


assignment: left_hand_side  ESITTIR assignment_expression ';'{$$ = $1 = $3};




%%
/* C Code*/

int computeSymbolIndex(char token)
{
    int idx = -1;
    if(islower(token)) {
        idx = token - 'a' + 26;
    } else if(isupper(token)) {
        idx = token - 'A';
    }
    return idx;
} 

int symbolVal(char symbol)
{
    int bucket = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    return symbols[bucket];
}

void updateSymbolVal(char symbol, int val)
{
    int bucket = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    symbols[bucket] = val;
}

int main (void) {
    /* init symbol table */
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
        symbols[i] = 0;
    }

    return yyparse ( );
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
 fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
 return 0;
}
int main(void) {
 yyparse();
 return 0;
}
```

I'm getting these warnings from yacc about useless rules in my grammar:

```
corona.y: uyarı: 4 nonterminals useless in grammar [-Wother]
corona.y: uyarı: 15 rules useless in grammar [-Wother]
corona.y:57.107-116: uyarı: nonterminal useless in grammar: expression [-Wother]
 %type <num>  assignment_expression relational_expression assignment conditional_expression left_hand_side expression
                                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:57.36-56: uyarı: nonterminal useless in grammar: relational_expression [-Wother]
 %type <num>  assignment_expression relational_expression assignment conditional_expression left_hand_side expression
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:57.14-34: uyarı: nonterminal useless in grammar: assignment_expression [-Wother]
 %type <num>  assignment_expression relational_expression assignment conditional_expression left_hand_side expression
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:57.58-67: uyarı: nonterminal useless in grammar: assignment [-Wother]
 %type <num>  assignment_expression relational_expression assignment conditional_expression left_hand_side expression
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:66.13-48: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 expression: assignment_expression ';' {$$ = $1;}
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:67.13-48: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
           | relational_expression ';' {$$ = $1;};
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:69.24-81: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 relational_expression: expression  ESITTIR expression  ';'      { $$ = $1 == $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:70.24-80: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  KUCUKTUR expression  ';'     { $$ = $1 < $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:71.24-81: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  KUCUKESIT expression  ';'    { $$ = $1 <= $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:72.24-80: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  BUYUKTUR expression  ';'     { $$ = $1 > $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:73.24-81: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  BUYUKESIT expression ';'     { $$ = $1 => $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:74.24-82: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  ANCAKVEANCAK expression ';'  { $$ = $1 <=> $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:75.24-81: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  DEMEK expression     ';'     { $$ = $1 => $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:76.24-81: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  VE expression    ';'         { $$ = $1 && $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:77.24-81: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  VEYA expression   ';'        { $$ = $1 || $3;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:78.24-81: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |expression  DEGIL expression  ';'        { $$ = $1 != $3;};
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:80.24-60: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 assignment_expression: conditional_expression ';' {$$ = $1;}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:81.24-60: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
                       |assignment           ';'   {$$ = $1;};
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
corona.y:84.13-75: uyarı: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 assignment: left_hand_side  ESITTIR assignment_expression ';'{$$ = $1 = $3};
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yacc/bison (and, indeed, most parser generators) assume that the target of the first production in your file is the non-terminal which the parser should match. But your first non-terminal is

```
type : YAZIDIZISI |
       SAYI
```

which bison/yacc takes to mean that the input can be either the token `YAZIDIZISI` or the token `SAYI`, and nothing else. That means that none of your other non-terminals are useful, so bison warns you about that.

If you don't want bison/yacc to guess where to start, you can specify the starting rule explicitly:

```
%start expression
```

Otherwise, you can move your rules around so that the top-level rule comes first.